# JasperXlsxExporterBuilder not loads WorkbookTemplate

Tags: excel, dynamic-reports

I'm using Dynamic Reports lib.
I'm trying to load a xlsx template to my export builder.

See the example:

```
JasperXlsxExporterBuilder xlsxExporter = export.xlsxExporter("final_file.xlsx");                    
xlsxExporter.setWorkbookTemplate("workbook_template.xlsx");
```

However this method (setWorkbookTemplate) does not work. The .xlsx template file is not loaded when final file generates: *report.toXlsx(xlsxExporter)*.

This is the complete code:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.builder.JasperReportBuilder;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.builder.export.JasperXlsxExporterBuilder;
import static net.sf.dynamicreports.report.builder.DynamicReports.cmp;
import static net.sf.dynamicreports.report.builder.DynamicReports.col;
import static net.sf.dynamicreports.report.builder.DynamicReports.export;
import static net.sf.dynamicreports.report.builder.DynamicReports.report;
import static net.sf.dynamicreports.report.builder.DynamicReports.type;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.report.datasource.DRDataSource;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
/**
 *
 * @author diego.queres
 */
public class TesteCargaXLSXPuro {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{

        JasperXlsxExporterBuilder xlsxExporter = export.xlsxExporter("/home/diego.queres/Área de Trabalho/final_file.xlsx");
        xlsxExporter.setWorkbookTemplate("/home/diego.queres/Área de Trabalho/TemplateTeste.xlsx");
        xlsxExporter.addSheetName("teste");
        xlsxExporter.setWhitePageBackground(Boolean.TRUE);

        report()//create new report design
                .columns(//add columns
                        //            title,     field name     data type
                        col.column("Item", "item", type.stringType()),
                        col.column("Quantity", "quantity", type.integerType()),
                        col.column("Unit price", "unitprice", type.bigDecimalType()))
                .title(cmp.text("Getting started"))//shows report title
                .pageFooter(cmp.pageXofY())//shows number of page at page footer
                .setDataSource(createDataSource())//set datasource
                .export(xlsxExporter);

    }

    private static JRDataSource createDataSource() {

        DRDataSource dataSource = new DRDataSource("item", "quantity", "unitprice");

        dataSource.add("Notebook", 1, new BigDecimal(500));

        dataSource.add("DVD", 5, new BigDecimal(30));

        dataSource.add("DVD", 1, new BigDecimal(28));

        dataSource.add("DVD", 5, new BigDecimal(32));

        dataSource.add("Book", 3, new BigDecimal(11));

        dataSource.add("Book", 1, new BigDecimal(15));

        dataSource.add("Book", 5, new BigDecimal(10));

        dataSource.add("Book", 8, new BigDecimal(9));

        return dataSource;

    }

}
```

Comment: can you provide small example of this?

Comment: yes. i will edit the post and put it